# How to print x number of items per line

Tags: python, python-2.7, line

I was going to ask this question on here. But I solved it just before I did. I wanted to be able to print this Python 2.7 list in a more orderly fashion.

```
not_shuffled_deck = ["%i of %s" % (i, s) for i in range(2,10) for s in ('spades', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'hearts')]

for i in not_shuffled_deck:
    print i + "|",
```

This is how it was originally turning out.

Well, it's actually worse than how it shows on here. It depends on the console size, screen size, if there is a text wrap, or not, etc. So in the consoles I've used or even in a normal text editor it will show up on multiple lines in a hard to read fashion.

```
 2 of spades| 2 of diamonds| 2 of clubs| 2 of hearts| 3 of spades| 3 of diamonds| 3 of clubs| 3 of hearts| 4 of spades| 4 of diamonds| 4 of clubs| 4 of hearts| 5 of spades| 5 of diamonds| 5 of clubs| 5 of hearts| 6 of spades| 6 of diamonds| 6 of clubs| 6 of hearts| 7 of spades| 7 of diamonds| 7 of clubs| 7 of hearts| 8 of spades| 8 of diamonds| 8 of clubs| 8 of hearts| 9 of spades| 9 of diamonds| 9 of clubs| 9 of hearts|
```

So I wanted a way to just print the four 2's on one line, then the 3's, etc.. With a space in between each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group on the first item in the string:

```
from itertools import groupby

for _, group in groupby(not_shuffled_deck, lambda c: c.split()[0]):
    print '| '.join(group)
    print
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> not_shuffled_deck = ["%i of %s" % (i, s) for i in range(2,10) for s in ('spades', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'hearts')]
>>> for _, group in groupby(not_shuffled_deck, lambda c: c.split()[0]):
...     print '| '.join(group)
...     print
... 
2 of spades| 2 of diamonds| 2 of clubs| 2 of hearts

3 of spades| 3 of diamonds| 3 of clubs| 3 of hearts

4 of spades| 4 of diamonds| 4 of clubs| 4 of hearts

5 of spades| 5 of diamonds| 5 of clubs| 5 of hearts

6 of spades| 6 of diamonds| 6 of clubs| 6 of hearts

7 of spades| 7 of diamonds| 7 of clubs| 7 of hearts

8 of spades| 8 of diamonds| 8 of clubs| 8 of hearts

9 of spades| 9 of diamonds| 9 of clubs| 9 of hearts
```

You asked:

> Can you give me an explanation in laymens term of how the formula
>   works?

This all pivots around the `lambda` function; `groupby()` takes each value from `not_shuffled_deck` and only looks at the output of that function. `c.split()` splits the card string on whitespace and only the first element is returned, so `'2'` or `'3'`, etc.

So `groupby` then produces groups where the first character is equal; the first element, second element, third element and fourth element of your list all have `'2'` as the first thing in their strings. `_` will be set to `'2'` (but I ignore it here), and group is an iterable producing those 4 elements; we pass that value to `'| '.join()` to make a new string to print.

I always picture iterables as bucket-brigades; rows of people passing along buckets of water from a river or well or pump. Doesn't matter where the buckets come from, you have no idea how many will still come, but all you can do is take the next bucket. `groupby` is like someone organizing new mini bucket brigades for you giving you just a few of the buckets it handles.

So you ask `groupby` to group buckets by how many fishes were caught with the water. He'll first give you a person that says: I only give you buckets with 2 fishes in them. You keep asking for buckets, and at some point that person says: nope, out of buckets, I have no more for you. And you go back to the `groupby` arbiter, who says, here, a new person, and he'll only pass on buckets with 4 fishes. And then you talk to just the 4-fishes-bucket guy for a while.

In my answer, `not_shuffled_deck` is the well (it'll run out of water at some point), `groupby` doesn't count fishes but only looks at the first part of the string, and `group` is the person giving you buckets that all have the same first part of the string.

Because this is a bucket brigade, `groupby` has no idea what'll come next, so if there is a bunch of buckets with 2 fishes, then followed by a bunch with 3 fishes, then another bunch with just 2 fishes again, you'll get 3 different people handing you 3 different groups of buckets. Groups are formed when the outcome of the `key` (the second argument to `groupby`) *changes* from bucket to bucket. Also, if you don't take all the buckets from the `group` person, then `groupby` will toss away buckets. *Empty them right onto the ground*.

If you were taking a 2-fishes group of buckets, but went back to the `groupby` arbiter to ask for a new group person, the arbiter would toss out all buckets with 2 fishes in them until it found a bucket with a different number of fishes before giving you a new person to talk to. You cannot then go back to the 2-fishes-group person and ask for more buckets, those buckets have all been emptied out on the street now.

Comment: @lostsock: thanks for the edit; I've added a little formatting to the text and removed my comments here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.islice` to evenly split the list into groups of 4.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> from math import ceil
>>> it = iter(not_shuffled_deck)
for _ in xrange(int(math.ceil(len(not_shuffled_deck)/4.))):
    data = islice(it, 4)
    print '| '.join(data)
...     
2 of spades| 2 of diamonds| 2 of clubs| 2 of hearts
3 of spades| 3 of diamonds| 3 of clubs| 3 of hearts
4 of spades| 4 of diamonds| 4 of clubs| 4 of hearts
5 of spades| 5 of diamonds| 5 of clubs| 5 of hearts
6 of spades| 6 of diamonds| 6 of clubs| 6 of hearts
7 of spades| 7 of diamonds| 7 of clubs| 7 of hearts
8 of spades| 8 of diamonds| 8 of clubs| 8 of hearts
9 of spades| 9 of diamonds| 9 of clubs| 9 of hearts
```

---

Or using list slicing(`slice notation`):

```
>>> n = int(math.ceil(len(not_shuffled_deck)/4.))
>>> for i in xrange(0, n*4, 4): 
    print '| '.join(not_shuffled_deck[i:i+4])
...     
2 of spades| 2 of diamonds| 2 of clubs| 2 of hearts
3 of spades| 3 of diamonds| 3 of clubs| 3 of hearts
4 of spades| 4 of diamonds| 4 of clubs| 4 of hearts
5 of spades| 5 of diamonds| 5 of clubs| 5 of hearts
6 of spades| 6 of diamonds| 6 of clubs| 6 of hearts
7 of spades| 7 of diamonds| 7 of clubs| 7 of hearts
8 of spades| 8 of diamonds| 8 of clubs| 8 of hearts
9 of spades| 9 of diamonds| 9 of clubs| 9 of hearts
```

Answer (score 1):

And this is the answer I came up with, that not only works for what I need now, but also for a number of other possibilities that might arise in the future.

```
not_shuffled_deck = ["%i of %s" % (i, s) for i in range(2,10) for s in ('spades', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'hearts')]

i = 0
for eachCard in not_shuffled_deck:
    if i % 4 == 0 and i != 0:
        print "\n"
        print eachCard + "|",
        i += 1
    else:
        print eachCard + "|",
        i += 1
```

which prints out

```
2 of spades| 2 of diamonds| 2 of clubs| 2 of hearts| 

3 of spades| 3 of diamonds| 3 of clubs| 3 of hearts| 

4 of spades| 4 of diamonds| 4 of clubs| 4 of hearts| 

5 of spades| 5 of diamonds| 5 of clubs| 5 of hearts| 

6 of spades| 6 of diamonds| 6 of clubs| 6 of hearts| 

7 of spades| 7 of diamonds| 7 of clubs| 7 of hearts| 

8 of spades| 8 of diamonds| 8 of clubs| 8 of hearts| 

9 of spades| 9 of diamonds| 9 of clubs| 9 of hearts|
```

Comment: You can move the `print eachCard + '"|",` and `i += 1` lines out of the `if` statement, and remove the `else` block altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution using join and split:

```
not_shuffled_deck = ["%i of %s" % (i, s) for i in range(2,10) for s in ('spades', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'hearts')]
print(" " +"hearts\n".join("| ".join(not_shuffled_deck).split("hearts|")))
```

Answer (score 0):

So **don't do it like this** because as @MartijnPieters pointed out you're wasting cycles and memory to create a list of `None`s, but here was my answer using a list comprehension (because I love them!)

```
my_deck_with_returns = []

[my_deck_with_returns.append(' {} of {} |'.format(i, s))
 for i in range(2,10) for s in ('spades', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'hearts')
 if s != 'spades' or not my_deck_with_returns.append('\n')]

print ''.join(my_deck_with_returns)
```

Scroll below for a suggestion by @MartijnPieters which preserves awesomeness while using only the necessary resources.

Comment: In general: don't ever use a list comprehension for the side effects. Especially not if the side effects are to build a list!

Comment: Because you are wasting memory and cycles. Now you have built a list of `None` references that is discarded again.

Comment: `['{} {} of {} |'.format('\n' if s == 'spades' else '', i, s) for i in range(2,10) for s in ('spades', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'hearts')]` would work too. Or use nested list comprehensions and `str.join()`.

Comment: Hmm I must agree. I liked your option very much.

Comment: You mean the [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), `true_expression if test_expression else false_expression`? You can put that anywhere you can use an expression.

Comment: Yes, because it is an expression there *must* be an outcome.

Comment: I imagined it was the case! Thank you very much!